# Override Spring Filter in Hybris

Tags: spring, filter, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud, spring-filter

I would like to override doFilter method of OOTB filter "RememberMeAuthenticationFilter" in order to add few more conditions in try block . I tried using below in spring-security-config.xml  :

```
<security:custom-filter position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER" ref="myRememberMeFilter"/>

<bean id="myRememberMeFilter"
        class="com.dfg.storefront.security.rememberme.MyRememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="myRememberMeServices" />
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="loginGuidAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    </bean>
```

But when I open website I get 404 error . Could someone please suggest how to override "RememberMeAuthenticationFilter" in hybris application.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `<security:custom-filter...../>`, you can override OOTB bean using alias

```
<alias name="myRememberMeFilter" alias="rememberMeProcessingFilter"/>
<bean id="myRememberMeFilter"
    class="com.dfg.storefront.security.rememberme.DfgRememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="myRememberMeServices" />
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="loginGuidAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I tried this way also , but still flow is going in OOTB filter and not in my custom filter. Please suggest some other solution